# FreeBSD: problem with Postfix after updating LDAP

Tags: postfix, ldap, freebsd

At the server I installed **openldap-server**, at this computer open-ldap client has already  been installed. Version of **openldap-client (2.4.16)** was older then new **openldap-server (2.4.21)** and the version of client has updated too. **OpenLDAP-client** works with **postfix** on this server and after all updates postfix cann't start again. The error when postfix stop|start is:

> /libexec/ld-elf.so.1: Shared object
>   "libldap-2.4.so.6" not found, required
>   by "postfix"

At the category with libraries is **libldap-2.4.so.7**, but **libldap-2.4.so.6** is removed from the server. When I want to deinstall curently version of openldap-client, system write

```
===>  Deinstalling for net/openldap24-client 

O.K., but when I start "make install" system write:
===>  Installing for openldap-sasl-client-2.4.23
===>   openldap-sasl-client-2.4.23 depends on shared library: sasl2.2 - found
===>   Generating temporary packing list
===>  Checking if net/openldap24-client already installed
===>   An older version of net/openldap24-client is already installed (openldap-client-2.4.21)
      You may wish to ``make deinstall'' and install this port again
      by ``make reinstall'' to upgrade it properly.
      If you really wish to overwrite the old port of net/openldap24-client
      without deleting it first, set the variable "FORCE_PKG_REGISTER"
      in your environment or the "make install" command line.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/net/openldap24-client.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/net/openldap24-client.
```

Updating of ports doesn't help, and **postfix writes error**:

> /libexec/ld-elf.so.1: Shared object
>   "libldap-2.4.so.6" not found, required
>   by "postfix"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You upgraded your OpenLDAP client, which deleted the old version of the shared library.  Postfix was built and linked against that old version of the shared library, and since it no longer exists Postfix can't start.

Re-compile postfix (which will cause it to link against the new version of the library) and this problem will go away.

In the future you can avoid problems like this by using `portupgrade` (check out the `-r` flag, which will recursively re-build packages that depend on the one being upgraded).